# r data.table - tstrsplit function - first column is blank when column starts with matching string

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to split the string as below

```
x <- data.table(VAROLD=c('DBA','ADB'))
x[, paste0('VARNEW_', 1:2) := tstrsplit(VAROLD, 'D', fixed=T)][]
```

I am getting output as below would like to see if I can avoid generating 1st column blank. I am only looking at options using data.table package.

| VAROLD | VARNEW_1 | VARNEW_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1: DBA |  | BA |
| 2: ADB | A | B |

Comment: What is your expected for first column

Comment: VARNEW_1 should be "BA" and VARNEW_2 should be blank (for 1st row and 2nd row as is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, we may need some substring shifting when 'D' occurs as the first character

```
x[, paste0('VARNEW_', 1:2) := tstrsplit(sub("^(D)(.*)", "\\2\\1", 
      VAROLD), "D", fixed = TRUE)][]
```

-output

```
  VAROLD VARNEW_1 VARNEW_2
1:    DBA       BA     <NA>
2:    ADB        A        B
```

---

Or if it is only the initial 'D', then remove that before doing the split

```
x[, paste0('VARNEW_', 1:2) := tstrsplit(sub("^D+", "", 
       VAROLD), "D", fixed = TRUE)][]
   VAROLD VARNEW_1 VARNEW_2
1:    DBA       BA     <NA>
2:    ADB        A        B
```

Comment: thanks, is this going to work if I have more than 2 elements. e.g. in above examples, I am creating 2 columns but what if I have 5 columns?

Comment: @R007 probably you need to show a better example as your examples are only showing for a simple case

Comment: @R007 i.e. what if "D" is the last character, then what its behavior would be etc.?

Comment: I think the problem is with when the string starts with a split character. (having D at the end is not going to be a problem.). Maybe easier to check if string start with split charactrer and then replace that with blank value and then pass on to tstrsplit()

Comment: @R007 maybe the updated code works fo ryou